# Exporting Firestore data using 'gcloud' into a different collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Problem:

I have orders in two different projects: `project-a:/documents/orders`, and `project-b:/documents/orders` (about half a million).

I need to import the orders from project-b into `project-a:/documents/orders_OLD`. Orders from project-b is in an older format, that needs to be converted into the never format thats in project-a: A task that would be easier if they were in the same database to begin with.

I know I can export them into a bucket from project-a, and copy to a bucket in project-b. But is it possible to then import it into a DIFFERENT collection? Most examples seems to focus on the same collection.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your use case:

1. I created a project (project-b) with Firestore.
2. I created a new collection.
3. I exported the collection to GCS:

   ```
     gcloud beta firestore export  gs://test-bucket  --collection-ids='my-colection'
   ```
4. I changed to the other project where I want to import the collection:

   ```
     gcloud config set project project-a
   ```
5. Set the app engine default service account (projecta@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) Stoage Admin Role on project-b to be able to access the buckets. You do not need to copy to a bucket to project-a.
6. I imported the collection:

   ```
     gcloud beta firestore import gs://project-b/file/  --collection-ids='my-colection'
   ```

Can you please explain what do you mean:

> But is it possible to then import it into a DIFFERENT collection? Most
>   examples seems to focus on the same collection.

If you would like to import the collection inside another document collection using `gcloud` command [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/firestore/import), the format does not support it:

```
    gcloud beta firestore import INPUT_URI_PREFIX [--async] [--collection-ids=[COLLECTION_IDS,…]]
```

Comment: Thought I explained quite clearly that I wanted `project-b:/documents/orders` into `project-a:/documents/orders_OLD`. Anyway I ended up copying everything from project-b:/documents/orders to project-b:/documents/orders_OLD, and then using gcloud to export that collection. Thanks for your answer though, I'll leave this open until they have an actual (if ever) way of doing my use case.